# How do you factorize $1-x-x^2$?

Tags: functions

I know this is a basic question, but I just got confused. So, if anyone could clear this out for me.

In this book that I'm reading, they factorized $1-x-x^2  = (1- \alpha x)(1- \beta x)$
where

$\alpha$ = $\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$
and 
$\beta$ = $\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}$.

Explain/Prove.

Comment: Technically, they are the inverses of the roots of that polynomial. @Peter They are the roots of $y^2-y-1=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, $$1-x-x^2=(1-\alpha x)(1-\beta x)=1-(\alpha+\beta)x+\alpha \beta x^2$$

Comparing the corresponding coefficients of both the sides, we get

$$\alpha+\beta=1\tag 1$$
$$\alpha\beta=-1\tag 2$$
Now, we have $$(\alpha-\beta)^2=(\alpha+\beta)^2-4\alpha \beta=(1)^2-4(-1)=5$$
$$\alpha-\beta=\sqrt5\tag 3$$
or  $$\alpha-\beta=- \sqrt5\tag 4$$
Now, solving (1) & (3), we gets $$\color{blue}{\alpha=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}, \ \ \beta=\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}}$$
If we solve (1) & (4) the roots are just interchanged as follows
$$\alpha=\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}, \ \ \beta=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

Since
$$
(1-\alpha x)(1-\beta x)=1-(\alpha+\beta)x+\alpha\beta x^2
$$
we must have $\alpha+\beta=1$ and $\alpha\beta=-1$. That is $\alpha(1-\alpha)=-1$ or $\alpha^2-\alpha-1=0$. Therefore, using the quadratic formula,
$$
\alpha=\frac{1\pm\sqrt5}2
$$
whichever choice we make for $\alpha$, we get the other for $\beta=1-\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is also essentially the same as finding the roots of this polynomial as a function.

$1-x-x^2=-(x^2+x+\frac{1}{4})+\frac{5}{4}=-(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{5}{4}=0$

$(x+\frac{1}{2})^2=\frac{5}{4}$

$x=-\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Then you realize that we are off by a scalar ($-1$).